# Testing the type of a C# object

Tags: c#

I have often wondered which is the better way of checking the type of an object before carrying out an operation.

I could use the 'is' operator:

```
if(obj is MyClass){
    var tObj = obj as MyClass;
}
```

Or I could use the 'as' operator and test for null:

```
var tObj = obj as MyClass;

if(tObj != null){

}
```

Is one preferable to the other? Is one way quicker? Does it matter?

Comment: you can also use obj.GetType()

Comment: I am making the assumption that I am working with a known set of types.

Answer (score 0):

Second way is preferable, because it is quicker.

In the second way you only call the operator `as` once and do a null check which is much more cheaper compared to `as`/`is` operators.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are using it,

For example, if the visibility of panels depends on the type of an object, then `is` would be better since you may not need to use the object again.

But for the examples you have provided, `as` would be better since you have a working object to use.